# test cases for scrapy spider. python

Tags: python, scrapy

is there a way i can write test cases for my scrapy spider i written that gives ouptut
eg:[
{"company_name": "A + Communications and Security", "source_url": "/company/a--communications-and-security"},
{"company_name": "A&A Technology Group", "source_url": "/company/a-a-technology-group"}]

```
import scrapy

class CompanySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'company'
    start_urls = ['https://www.adapt.io/directory/industry/telecommunications/A-1']
    custom_settings = {"TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED" : False,"ROBOTSTXT_OBEY" : False}
    
    def parse(self,response):
        for company in response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'DirectoryList_link')]"):
            yield{
                'company_name' : company.xpath("./a/text()").get(),
                'source_url' : company.xpath("./a/@href").get().split('https://www.adapt.io')[-1]
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Spiders Contracts](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/contracts.html) or local fake responses which reflect the state of the website the moment you mapped it.

[How to work with the scrapy contracts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764201/how-to-work-with-the-scrapy-contracts)