# Isolated Scrapy HTTP request with loaded settings

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to write a unit test to the Scrapy spider. The problem is, the only way I know on how to call Scrapy spider programmatically is through `scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess` which creates subprocess, then Twisted reactor, etc. For simple unit test it's a massive overkill.

What I want to do is simply create a request, load project settings somehow, send it and process the response.

Is there a way to do it properly?

**EDIT.** 
I checked [Scrapy Unit Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456304/scrapy-unit-testing), but the whole point of the test is to check how some xpaths in the database map on the current state of the website. I'm ok with the online testing, I need it actually. 
(Then it's becoming more like an integration test, but whatever.)