# Test scrapy spider still working - find page changes

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests, scrapy

> How can I test a scrapy spider against **online** data.

I now from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456304/scrapy-unit-testing) post that it is possible to test a spider against **offline** data.

My target is to check if my spider still extracts the right data from a page, or if the page changed. I extract the data via XPath and sometimes the page receives and update and my scraper is no longer working. I would love to have the test as close to my code as possible, eg. using the spider and scrapy setup and just hook into the parse method.

Comment: Have you tried Spider Contracts? http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/contracts.html

Comment: Yes, thank you. It is my plan B, still I would like a real "test" because I want to do more after the check.

Comment: Write a scrapy pipeline for the data values that you expect. If your scraper doesn't scrape the expected value for the field then you should raise the scrapy [DropItem](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/exceptions.html#dropitem) exception

Comment: Does that address your issue? --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456304/scrapy-unit-testing/38214137#38214137

Comment: Sounds like it, I will look into it! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to the link you provided, you could try this method for online testing which I used for my problem which was similar to yours. All you have to do is instead of reading the requests from a file you can use the Requests library to fetch the live webpage for you and compose a scrapy response from the response you get from Requests like below

```
import os
import requests

from scrapy.http import Response, Request

def online_response_from_url (url=None):

    if not url:
        url = 'http://www.example.com'

    request = Request(url=url)


    oresp = requests.get(url)

    response = TextResponse(url=url, request=request,
    body=oresp.text, encoding = 'utf-8')

    return response
```