# Create unit-test for method of scrapy CrawlSpider

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, scrapy

## The initial problem

I am writing a CrawlSpider class (using the `scrapy` library) and rely on a lot of `scrapy` *asynchronous magic* to make it work. Here it is, stripped down:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='myregex'), callback='parse_page')]
    # some other class attributes

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.response = None
        self.loader = None

    def parse_page_section(self):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.response.body, 'lxml')
        # Complicated scraping logic using BeautifulSoup
        self.loader.add_value(mykey, myvalue)

    # more methods parsing other sections of the page
    # also using self.response and self.loader

    def parse_page(self, response):
        self.response = response
        self.loader = ItemLoader(item=Item(), response=response)
        self.parse_page_section()
        # call other methods to collect more stuff
        self.loader.load_item()
```

The class attribute `rule` tells my spider to follow certain links and jump to a **callback function** once the web-pages are downloaded. My goal is to test the parsing method called `parse_page_section` without running the crawler or even making real HTTP requests.

## What I tried

Instinctively, I turned myself to the `mock` library. I understand how you mock a function to test whether it has been called (with which arguments and if there were any side effects...), but that's not what I want. I want to instantiate a fake object `MySpider` and assign just enough attributes to be able to call `parse_page_section` method on it.

In the above example, I need a `response` object to instantiate my `ItemLoader` and specifically a `self.response.body` attribute to instantiate my `BeautifulSoup`. In principle, I could make fake objects like this:

```
from argparse import Namespace

my_spider = MySpider(CrawlSpider)
my_spider.response = NameSpace(body='<html>...</html>')
```

That works well to for the `BeautifulSoup` class but I would need to add more attributes to create an `ItemLoader` object. For more complex situations, it would become ugly and unmanageable.

## My question

Is this the right approach altogether? I can't find similar examples on the web, so I think my approach may be wrong at a more fundamental level. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ChrisP thanks for your edit. I did not put the `scrapy` label in the first place because I thought the question had to do with unit-testing in general.

Comment: It's definitely unit testing in general, but people who do lots of scraping might have some unique insights for unit testing scrapers.

Comment: In this particular `CrawlSpider` case, I could get away with faking a response object. Doing it by hand is difficult, but could this help? http://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html. Would this be a good approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you seen [Spiders Contracts](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/contracts.html)?

This allows you to test each callback of your spider without requiring a lot of code. For example:

```
def parse(self, response):
    """ This function parses a sample response. Some contracts are mingled
    with this docstring.

    @url http://www.amazon.com/s?field-keywords=selfish+gene
    @returns items 1 16
    @returns requests 0 0
    @scrapes Title Author Year Price
    """
```

Use the [check](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html#std:command-check) command to run the contract checks.

Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12741030/2207154), if you want something even bigger.

Comment: I guess it makes sense to go for *real life* (integration) tests instead of unit testing since the website itself can change. In essence, the fact that your unit tests work doesn't ensure that your scraping works. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: There is still value in unit-tests though, as sanity checks whilst coding at the very least. The other answer you provide (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456304/scrapy-unit-testing/12741030#12741030] shows how to fake a response object in a better way, by actually using `scrapy` `Request` and `Response` objects. Nice tip.